# Speeding up Google Sheets DeveloperMetadataFinder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, metadata, google-sheets-api

I have a small (~50 rows, ~5 cols of data) spreadsheet with metadata attached to many of the rows. I'm trying to find the fastest way to iterate over the metadata for those rows.

Getting the data for the rows (the time between 'a' and 'b') is on the order of 100ms.
Getting the metadata for the same rows using [DeveloperMetadataFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata-finder) (the time between 'b' and 'c') is on the order of 10 seconds!

```
  console.log('a ' + Date.now());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();

  console.log('b ' + Date.now());
  // between b and c is where all the time is taken up
  var metadata = range.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().withKey(METADATA_KEY).withLocationType(SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.ROW).find().reduce( (sum, md) => {
    sum[md.getLocation().getRow().getRowIndex()] = md.getValue();
    return sum;
  }, {});  
  console.log('c ' + Date.now());
```

I also tried limiting the rows to just the rows containing data:

```
var metadata = sheet.getRange(1,1,range.getNumRows(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).createDeveloperMetadataFinder() ...
```

but that didn't appear to be any faster.

`md.getLocation()` seems to be what's causing the script to be slow. `md.getValue()` is fine, but if I comment out `md.getLocation()` the script speeds up by orders of magnitude.

Is there a faster way I can get all the metadata tags for this range?

Comment: As  you've tagged, [tag:google-sheets-api] is usually faster. Try advanced Google services from within Apps script.

Comment: That may be an option. I've narrowed it down to the use of DeveloperMetadata.getLocation(). getValue() is fine, but if I comment out getLocation() the script speeds up considerably.

Comment: Ok, but you need location right?

Comment: Yes, I just need the row index to match the metadata to the data in the row

Comment: Have you tried using the google sheet api? Did you see an improve?